# The xsp4 web server cannot be fo found .Please insure it is installed

Tags: c#, mono, fedora

I have MonoDevelop on Fedora 21.

Target Framework : Mono/4.5

I tried to change the framework , but no change. Also cant find "mono" in /usr

Not able to find "rpm" for XSP4 for Fedora21.

Much appreciated if someone knows how to install the right server for asp.net on fedora.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to wait until the exciting full release of vNext which will include

New flexible and cross-platform runtime 
Ability to self-host

"ASP.NET vNext (and Rosyln) runs on Mono, on both Mac and Linux today. While Mono isn't a project from Microsoft, we'll collaborate with the Mono team, plus Mono will be added to our test matrix. It's our aspiration that it "just work." "- SCOTT HANSELMAN

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx